# TYPO3 TCA selectMultiple config

Tags: typo3

I've an issue wit TYPO3 selectField, selectMultipleSideBySide.

I've configure the field like this:

```
$tmpColumns = [
    'tx_tcademo_list' => [
        'label' => 'Items',
        'config' => [
            'type' => 'select',
            'renderType' => 'selectMultipleSideBySide',
            'foreign_table' => 'tx_tcademo_domain_model_item',
            'MM' => 'tx_tcademo_record_item_mm',
            'MM_hasUidField' => true,
            'MM_match_fields' => [
                'tablenames' => 'fe_users',
                'fieldnames' => 'tx_tcademo_items',
            ],
            'minitems' => 0,
            'maxitems' => 99999,
        ],
    ],
];

\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTCAcolumns('fe_users', $tmpColumns);
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addToAllTCAtypes('fe_users', 'tx_tcademo_list');
```

Issue is:
The field is added to fe_users correctly, and items can be selected as expected, and they're saved to db MM relation, but when form is redrawn, the selected items are not marked as selected, and will be overwritten with next save.

Link to extension which demonstrates the issue:
[TCA Demo extension](https://github.com/TokeHerkild/tca_demo)

Comment: You're adding a field `tx_tcademo_list` to `fe_users`, but searching for matching values for  `fe_users.tx_tcademo_items`...

Comment: Seems that MM_match_fields is not doing as they're described in the documentation ? 
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/10.4/en-us/ColumnsConfig/Type/selectMultipleSideBySide.html#mm-match-fields

Comment: `MM_match_fields` configures a filter for the relation to `MM`. In the MM-table, there can be a column `tablenames` and `fieldnames`, because the table can be used for different relations to `tx_tcademo_domain_model_item`. Your configuration of `MM_match_fields` matches those  MM relations having `tablenames='fe_users'` and `fieldnames='tx_tcademo_items'`. But your relation is to filed 'tx_tcademo_list', not to 'tx_tcademo_items'. So, your condition does not match.

Comment: I'm sorry to inform you, but that does absolutely no difference. As soon as MM_match_fields is activated the MM relation fails to work. When going throug xDebug, I found that when MM_match_fields is used, foreign_table and local_table seems to be switched, Or when runnig PHP Debug, when RelationHandler completes foereign_table equals local_table.

Comment: Nope, switching the direction is `MM_opposite_field`.
`MM_match_fields` adds additional `AND`-statements to the SQL query:
https://github.com/TYPO3/typo3/blob/master/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Database/RelationHandler.php#L572

Comment: That part works as it should, but I've still to figure out why local_table is queried using the result set of the MM,  instead of foreign_table.